# Is it possible to configure all things from system.web in system.webserver?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I find it really hard to find clear documentation on IIS7 and integrated mode. Apparently the system.webserver section is for IIS7 integrated mode... but, does IIS7 Integrated Mode ignore a system.web section? + Can you configure everything from the system.web section in the system.webserver section?

There's a tool to migrate from IIS6 to IIS7. If I run it, a lot of things still remain in system.web. Most application even run in Integrated Mode without changing web.config... so, please, explain me why there was a new section needed? I really don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

System.WebServer section is "processed" by IIS7 and the asp.net engine is not involved. Earlier (pre - IIS7), the configuration system of IIS (metabase.xml) and ASP.NET (the heirarchy of web.config) were completely different, but in IIS7 a unified configuration is generated at run time for app pool.

The IIS7 configuration file is stored here: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. This one has the system.WebServer.

This has architectural implications in the sense that (at least in theory) now asp.net modules can be executed even for a non asp.net application.

You can look at the default app pool config here: C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool

There are more details, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you said the documentation is hard to find, as Microsoft this time keeps a centralized portal for it,

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference

The changes made by the migration tool are all documented in this article,

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis/

You can read it through to understand why certain tags are modified.